# Problema conexion formulario a la base de datos php mysql

Tags: mysql, html5

Intento acceder desde un formulario a la base de datos, y no me lleva a ningún sitio. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar... mil gracias!

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        require '../php/Funciones.php';
        $obj = new Funciones();

        if(isset($POST['titulo'], $POST['contenido'])){
            $subir = $obj->subirPublicacion($_POST['titulo'], $_POST['contenido'], $_SESSION['admin']);

            if($subir == true){
                echo '<span class="alert alert-success ">Artículo dado de alta</span>';
            }
        }

?>
```

...

### Admin Panel

```
        <form action="http://localhost:8888/cmsbasico/admin/publicacion.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="user" class="form-control"/>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" class="form-control"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left" style="margin-top: 20px;" value="Iniciar sesión"/>
        </form>

    </div>
```

La función que estoy usando es:

```
public function logIn($user, $pass){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare("
                  SELECT *
                  FROM admins
                  WHERE usuario = :user AND pass = :pass
            ");
            $query->execute([
                'user' => $user,
                'pass' => $pass
            ]);

            return $query->fetch();

        }
```

Comment: David bienvenido a Stackoverflow.  En el código no se ve que llames a la función `logIn` en ninguna parte... Si no la llamas, no creo que venga. Saludos.

Comment: MIl gracias A. Cedano, lo miraré a ver si me funciona.

Comment: Ya que la función tiene un `return`, tienes que probarla con algo como: `$datos=logIn('tuusuario','tupassword');`  y para ver el resultado puedes poner a continuación: `$var_dump($datos);`

Comment: Mil gracias A. Cedano, soy muy nuevo en esto, he visto que  se me había olvidado incluir el formulario. No me entero de como funciona, ¿podrías poner un código de ejemplo?

Comment: Finalmente conseguí solucionar el problema. Había un return $query->fetch(); que tenía en el archivo de funciones, que sobraba.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo haya resuelto. Aunque sigo sin ver para que sirve la función `logIn` que has compartido aquí. No veo que la estés usando ni llamando en ninguna parte.